# Proof of Heine-Borel on the Complex Plane

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I'm reading Complex Analysis by Serge Lang and I'm having trouble understanding the proof that he presented for the Heine-Borel theorem:

[image: Image of Proof]

In particular, why is it that the presence of a subsequence converging to $a + ib$ implies that $S$ is compact? I can follow everything before that.

(The image is taken from this Math Stackexchange [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253826/heine-borel-theorem-on-the-complex-plane), which unfortunately doesn't answer my question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a metric space, you have the fact that sequentially compact is equivalent to compact, thus in $\mathbb{C}$ it suffices to show that any sequence in your set has a convergent subsequence, whose limit is in said set.